# subprocess.Popen' s stdin.buffer/stdout is never flushing

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, subprocess

I am writing a python daemon (using python 3.7) that continuously checks if data is available on stdin (using `select`) and does something with it. The data can contain non-unicode characters, so the daemon needs to read from `sys.stdin.buffer` instead of `sys.stdin`.

That program actually works. But I am writing a functional test for that program, using a second python script, that starts the daemon with `subprocess.Popen`, and sends data to it's `stdin` and reads from its `stdout`. For some reason, that part doesn't work. `proc.readline()` blocks forever, and some `proc.stdin.write` never reach the child process.

To boil it down, I have 2 small scripts that illustrate the problem.
Right now, the issue is that the first `readline()` call in test.py is blocking and never returning, while `test2.py` already wrote a full line to stdout.

```
# test.py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, TimeoutExpired
import time
import select

proc = Popen(["python", "test1.py"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE,
             bufsize=0)

print("Writing")
proc.stdin.write("blablabla\n".encode('utf-8'))
time.sleep(2)
output = proc.stdout.readline()
print("Result")
print(output)
print("Writing")
proc.stdin.write("zxczxczxczxc\n".encode('utf-8'))
time.sleep(2)
output = proc.stdout.readline()
print("Result")
print(output)
proc.terminate()
print(proc.stdout.read())
```

```
#test1.py
import select
import signal
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, stream=sys.stdout)
log = logging.getLogger()

STOP = False


def stop(frame, signal):
    global STOP
    STOP = False


signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, stop)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, stop)


def input_available():
    """Check if data is available on stdin."""
    data_available = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)
    return sys.stdin in data_available[0]

data = ""
while not STOP:
    if input_available():
        char = sys.stdin.buffer.read(1)
        try:
            char = char.decode('utf-8')
            data += char
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            char = None
            print("skipping char")
        if char == '\n':
            s = f"Got line {data}"
            print(s)
            log.debug(s)
            data = ""
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

**EDIT**
From the commment of @charles-duffy I ran it with strace. It seems that the program in the subprocess is blocking on it's `read` call?
This is the last bit of strace output:

```
write(1, "Writing\n", 8Writing
)                = 8
write(4, "blablabla\n", 10)             = 10
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=2, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
read(5,
```

Comment: Use strace, sysdig, or similar tools (`bpftrace` and kin have meant that there's something of a renaissance in low-overhead system-wide tracing in Linux right now). If the problem is that `readline()` is trying to read a larger chunk than the single line that's available without blocking, then you'll see that in the `read()` syscall parameters. If the problem *really is* that the write wasn't flushed, you'll see that too, because there won't actually be a `write()` syscall invocation.